# Show that if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, then there is exactly one $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x+y=0$

Tags: real-analysis, equivalence-relations

Show that if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, then there is exactly one $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x+y=0$. (Here 0 means $\langle 0,1 \rangle$)

Comment: *Hint:* If $x+y_1=0=x+y_2$ then by adding $y_1$ to both sides we get $(y_1+x)+y_1=(y_1+x)+y_2$

Comment: What do you mean by $0 = <0,1>$.

Comment: "Her $0$ meand $<0,1>$"... okay... what does $<0,1>$ mean? What axioms and definitions are you using?  By *my* definitions.  $0$ means $0$ and for every $q$ we have by axiom there exists a $-q$ so that $q+(-q)=-q+q =0$.  And it's easy to prove that if there is any other $r$ so that $q+r = 0$ then $-q = -q + 0 = -q + q + r = 0 + r = r$ so $-q$ is unique.  So *what* definitions and axioms are *you* using.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. By definition, there exist $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $b \neq 0$ such that $x = \frac{a}{b}$. Clearly, $y = \frac{-a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}$ since this is similarly a ratio of integers (and the integers are closed under multiplication). We have
$$x + y = \frac{a}{b} + \frac{-a}{b} = \frac{a + (-a)}{b} = \frac{0}{b} = 0.$$
This establishes the existence of such a $y$, so we may write $y = -x$.

To show that there is exactly one $y$, we must show uniqueness. Suppose $y_1$ and $y_2$ both have the property that $x + y_1 = 0$ and $x + y_2 = 0$. Then: 
$$y_1 = y_1 + 0 = y_1 + (x + y_2) = (y_1 + x) + y_2 = 0 + y_2 = y_2.$$
Hence, this $y$ we found is unique.

Comment: Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't assume that everyone is taking the same class as you are and defining the mathematical objects in the same way you are.

I'm assuming you have defined the rationals as the set of all ordered pairs of integers $(a,b); a,b \in \mathbb Z; b\ne 0$ but with the equivalence that $(a,b) = (c,d)$ if and only if $ab=bd$. And with addition and multiplication defined as $(a,b)\times (c,d) = (ac,bd)$ and $(a,b)+(c,d) = (ad+bc,bd)$.

In which case, for any $q=(a,b)$ then $(a,b) + (-a,b) = (ab+b(-a),b^2) = (ab-ab,b^2)= (0,b^2)$ and we have $(0,b^2) = (0,1)$ because $0*1 = b^2*0 = 0$.

And we know that if $(a,b)+(c,d) = (ad + bc,bd)=(0,1)$ then $ad+bc=(ad+bc)*1 = (bd)*0 = 0$.  So $bc=(-a)b$ and therefore $(-a,b)=(c,d)$ and $(-a,b)$ is the only such rational number.